# Copy ObservableList java

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, observablelist

I have a `masterData` which is an `ObservableList` and `filteredData` which is also an `ObservableList`.

Then, I want to use it to show the **filtered data when the filter is set**, but also to be able to **recover whenever necessary**. Here is the MCVE:

```
package br;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Main{
    private static ObservableList<Foo> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private static ObservableList<Foo> filteredData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    static Filter filter = new Filter();
    public static void addDummy(){
        masterData.add(new Foo("a",1));
        masterData.add(new Foo("aa",3));
        masterData.add(new Foo("b",2));
        masterData.add(new Foo("bb",4));
        masterData.add(new Foo("c",3));
    }
    public static void printData(ObservableList<Foo> list){
        for(Foo f: list) System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addDummy();
        applyFilter(3);
        printData(filteredData);
        applyFilter(0);
        printData(filteredData);
    }
    public static void applyFilter(int num){
        filter.setData(masterData);
        filter.setFilter(num);
        filteredData = filter.getData();
    }
}
```

**The class filter, which I use to filter the data:**

```
package br;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Filter {
    private ObservableList<Foo> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public void setFilter(int filter){
        List<Foo> copy = new ArrayList<Foo>(data);
        for(Foo f: copy)
            if(f.getBar()<filter) data.remove(f);
    }
    public ObservableList<Foo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ObservableList<Foo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And the `Foo` class, which is just a [String] `name` and a [int] `bar` (plus getters /setters)

```
package br;

public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private int bar;
    public Foo(String name, int bar){
        this.setBar(bar);
        this.setName(name);
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public int getBar() {return bar;}
    public void setBar(int bar) {this.bar = bar;}
}
```

When you run this code, you will get:

> aa
> bb
> c

Both when the filter was set to 3 (**which filtered the data as expected**) and after the filter was **"reset" to zero**.

How can I make sure the filter is always processed with the data in the **masterData** and then stored on the **filteredData** ?

*Note: this is for a JavaFX project, so I really need to use the `ObservableList`.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Problem**

```
public void setData(ObservableList<Foo> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

**Explanation**

In case you are wondering that Java obeys *Pass By Value* and the value of **masterData** should have been copied to the list **data**. You are correct ! But there is just a little twist to the story !

In case of *primitives*, the values are passed but in case of objects, *Object references are passed by value*.

So, you are referencing to the Object of the **masterData**, instead of copying the values to a new List !

**Solution**

```
this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data);
```

This will create a new Object for **data** to refer and all the manipulations will be done on this new object's data.

Comment: I just wanted to say this helped me out, thanks so much!

The FXCollections class is very useful in multiple instances!