# Maintain a copy of observable list

Tags: javafx, observablelist

I'm trying to create an  undo redo functionality on a table view. For this I tried to make a copy of the observable list(table view data) and maintain it as original for further reference.

```
    ObservableList<T> tableData = FXCollections.ObservableArrayList();
    table.setItems(tableData);
    ObservableList<T> originalList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(tableData);

    lblUndo.setOnMouseClicked((evt) -> {
            System.out.println("undo click == " + (originalList==data));
            System.out.println("undo click equals " + originalList.equals(data));
            table.setItems(originalList);
    });

    lblRedo.setOnMouseClicked((evt) -> {
            System.out.println("redo click " + originalList.equals(data));
            table.setItems(tableData);
    });
```

Now whatever changes I make to the `table` should be reflected only in `tableData` not in `originalList`. But both the list are carrying the updated data.

The output in console is

```
undo click == false
undo click equals true
redo click true
```

How can I maintain an original copy which should not get updated?

PS: I just have Observable list `tableData` as input, whatever source I got values for `tableData`,  I cannot use the same source to fill `originalList`.

Comment: The `originalList` references `tableData`. To achieve what you want you would have to clone one of the lists, to make it a separate instance.

Comment: @hotzst The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) say "Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it."

Comment: This works just fine for me. Can you create and post a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D For me both lists are getting updated whenever I make any change in the table. I want one list to carry original data and the other to carry the updated one.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D see the update

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441810/copy-observablelist-java

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I am using the solution mentioned there. But its not helping.

Comment: Are you talking about adding/removing elements from the list OR updating objects that are already in the list?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I am trying to create unod redo functionality. So i want to maintain one list with original data and the other list with the table updated data.